# How to do sharepoint people search via webservice?

Tags: search, web-services

I need to access search for people in SharePoint 2010 from a webservice.

I have tried this querypacket:

```
            sb.Append("<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>");
            sb.Append("<Query>");
            sb.Append("<Context>");
            sb.Append("<QueryText language=\"en-US\" type=\"MSSQLFT\">");
            sb.Append("SELECT ");
            sb.Append("preferredname, ");
            sb.Append("Department, ");
            sb.Append("WorkPhone, ");
            sb.Append("WorkEmail, ");
            sb.Append("Path ");
            sb.Append("FROM SCOPE() ");
            sb.Append("WHERE ");
            sb.Append("(\"DAV:contentclass\" = 'urn:content-class:SPSPeople') ");
            sb.Append(" AND (\"FirstName\" LIKE '" + fname + "%') AND (\"LastName\" LIKE '" + lname + "%')");             
            sb.Append("</QueryText>");
            sb.Append("</Context>");
            sb.Append("<Range><Count>" + resultcount.ToString() + "</Count></Range>");
            sb.Append("</Query>");
            sb.Append("</QueryPacket>");
```

but I get this error msg:

```
<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">
   <Response domain="">
      <Status>ERROR_SERVER</Status>   
      <DebugErrorMessage>System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException</DebugErrorMessage>
   </Response>
</ResponsePacket>
```

(reposted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/6580020/67249)

---UPDATE

I found a lab exercise to do this exact search at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg981317, And when I copied the query, I still got the `KeyNotFoundException` exception.
My query is not at fault. 
I am searching against the 2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine as per the Lab

---UPDATE 2
Copied the query from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/DepartmentPeopleViewer1.aspx?display=Print and STILL I got the `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException` message!

Searching for normal documents bring back results though.

---UPDATE 3

Using the tool suggested by Chris Beckett (thank you!) I run this query: `SELECT * FROM SCOPE() WHERE "scope"= 'People'`  and get the same error as above.

---UPDATE 4

I finally got results: the issue was not the queries, but the fact that the IW VM was using our company's DNS! Fixed that, and every people search works! Thank you for all the contributions!

Comment: does your "fname" or "lname" contains `'` char ? if yes, this may create a wrong query... you should escape this arguments

Comment: +1 for detailed error messages and steps to reproduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Search Query syntax is finicky and a lot of people have problems getting it just right. There is a fantastic tool you can use to test and customize your search query until you get it right:

<strike>www.mosssearch.com</strike> [<= URL seems to be invalid, looking for update. [RK](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4170/robert-kaucher)]

Download the search test tool, fill out the input fields, and it generates the Query Xml, and can even execute and return the results in Xml or Dataset format.

My next suggestion is to incrementally cut down the query until it executes (e.g. remove the And from the Where clause, remove fields from the Select clause) to try to isolate which part may be causing the problem.

UPDATE: I wish you had mentioned that you had FAST installed. Although the syntax is mostly the same for calling the search web service, when fast is installed you now have the option of submitting queries targeted at SharePoint Search using Keywords or SQL syntax, or FAST using FQL. This makes the syntax of the query that needs to be submitted a little different.

I cleaned up a copy of the request Xml to support a SharePoint server with FAST integration - you can download the sample here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3763013/SharePointStackExchange/PeopleSearchQuery.txt

Comment: I did try this tool, and somehow the Query still gives me the KeyNotFoundException while QueryEx returns a dataset when querytype is set to SQL (using the tool)

Comment: +1 for multiple troubleshooting steps the original poster values. Going the extra mile would be testing this on the IW VM.

Comment: Try the following - this query worked for me using the moss-search tool: "Select path from scope() where contentclass = 'urn:content-class:SPSPeople'

Comment: @Chris Beckett: I get 0 results when running your query on the [Information Worker VM](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21099#overview), which has a sps3 Content Source with 284 successful hits after  a crawl.
(using the mosssearch tool)

Comment: Chris, the link you give at the top is apparently no longer valid. I am going to remove the `a` tag until it can be updated.

Answer (score 3):

'Select * ' will not work, please try:

```
SELECT Path
FROM Scope()
WHERE "SCOPE" = 'People'
```

It looks like one (or more) of the fields you're using in the query don't exist.

Comment: Boerbbom: I get 0 results when running your query on the [Information Worker VM](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21099#overview), which has a sps3 Content Source with 284 successful hits after a crawl.(using the mosssearch tool)

Comment: And with SearchCoder? http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/releases

Comment: It connects fine, but when I Build/Execute SQL I get: "The given key was not present in the dictionary".  
Running the query as Web Service (Radio buttun on [RUN] tab) causes unhandled exception "Cannot find table 0"

Comment: You were running the above query I suggested?

Comment: yes, I was using your query.

Comment: I think you have other issues, this query is the most basic one and has to work.

Comment: Anita, you were right about me having other issues: see UPDATE #4 in my question above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This query Not working for workphone search.U have any Idea

Answer (score 0):

Stupid remark maybe, but:

- Does search for userprofiles work in your UI? you can check it out by entering "content-class:SPSPeople" in your searchbox.

  - Assuming this happens on your development box: try to run your query agains only your servername: http://servername/ instead of http://servername.domain.com. Localhost or 127.0.0.1 might be an option too

Comment: I did not get any results for your suggestion: "We did not find any results for content-class:SPSPeople."